# Cannot set a variable from stored function result in MySQL Update Statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a variable to hold the results of a stored function in MySQL.  I get a syntax error that I cannot reconcile when I try to set the variable.

The name of the function is checkAddress(v1, v2, v3, v4) and returns a string.  I want to put the results into a variable and then update two fields with parts of the returned string.

I am looking for the correct syntax to create and use a variable in an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE t1 n
JOIN t2 t ON n.id = t.id
SET @temp:=checkAddress(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3, t.v4),
n.address1 = LEFT(@temp, 10),
n.address2 = RIGHT(@temp, 20);
```

I get a syntax error at '@'.

I tried a test of the following:

```
SELECT @temp:=checkAddress(ADDRESS_1,ADDRESS_2,ADDRESS_3,ADDRESS_4) AS 'holder',
CONCAT("X",' ',@temp) FROM table;
```

This results in a column 'holder' with an 'X' prepended to the returned string from the function.  This was to prove that variables can be set in the system and the function works.

Note: The LEFT and RIGHT functions are for illustration purposes to show that I will use the @temp variable to set other fields.  It dose not matter what is after the SET @temp:= as I cannot get past this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1 n
JOIN t2 t ON n.id = t.id
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT checkAddress(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3, t.v4) tmp) tmp
SET n.address1 = LEFT(tmp.tmp, 10), n.address2 = RIGHT(tmp.tmp, 20);
```

https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/92ec633fe9d91409f5d890724199b9c8/

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x5BRNGAWzf6QXBoKvB2PEw/0

---

Also you may use inline assignment:

```
UPDATE t1 n
JOIN t2 t ON n.id = t.id
SET n.address1 = LEFT(@temp:=checkAddress(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3, t.v4), 10),
    n.address2 = RIGHT(@temp, 20);
```

This works correctly always - MySQL guarantees that the expressions in SET clause are evaluated in the order in which they are written in the SQL text. This behavior differs from standard SQL. See UPDATE Statement description in the Reference Manual for more information.

Comment: I am using mariadb version 10 so there is no LATERAL.  However the inline assignment works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly set user variables within an `UPDATE` statement. However, you can achieve your goal using a subquery to assign the result of the function to a variable and then use that variable in the `UPDATE` statement.

For example:

```sql
SET @temp := (SELECT checkAddress(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3, t.v4) FROM t1 n JOIN t2 t ON n.id = t.id);

UPDATE t1 n
JOIN t2 t ON n.id = t.id
SET n.address1 = LEFT(@temp, 10),
    n.address2 = RIGHT(@temp, 20);
```

The result of the `checkAddress` function for each corresponding record is stored in `@temp` variable through the subquery, and then you can use `@temp` in the subsequent `UPDATE` statement to set the values of address1 and address2.

> Important to note that this query assumes that you're updating `t1` based on the `JOIN` condition with `t2` and it's crucial that each record in `t1` has a corresponding match in `t2` based on the id column. Adjust the `JOIN` condition accordingly based on your schema.

Comment: Unfortunately, n.id is not known in the SET @temp statement as I get the following error: SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'n.id' in 'where clause'.

Comment: It is as simple as joining at SET @temp statement. You should change it to be as your join query from your example:

`SET @temp := (SELECT checkAddress(t.v1, t.v2, t.v3, t.v4) FROM t1 n JOIN t2 t ON n.id = t.id);`

Comment: Your example returns the error 'Your subquery returned more than 1 row'.  I tried all these permutations with no success.